# Regex in R to limit one term AND another not OR another

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to extract records from a data.frame using grepl. Here are some example cases.

`a <- c('This is a healthcare facility', 'this is a hospital', 'this is a hospital district', 'this is a district health service')`

I wish to extract all records that have hospital but not district. I have come unstuck when district and hospital occur in the same string. I tried using the dollowing:

`str_match(string=a,pattern='hospital|^district' )`

How do I limit district but still include hospital in this example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[R supports Perl-compatible regular expressions](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html), which allow negative lookahead assertions, so in principle, you can write:

```
str_match(string=a, pattern='^(?!.*district).*hospital', perl=TRUE)
```

(which matches "start-of-string, followed by a point in the string that is *not* followed by `.*district`, followed by `.*hospital`"). That said, I'm really not sure if putting this condition into a single regex is the *best* way to do it; there may be a more R-ish way.

Comment: Thanks @ruakh, the other 2 answers were effective but this one I chose because it gave a description of using lookahead assertions.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the symbol & for AND, ! for NOT, with two grepl calls:

```
grepl("hospital", a) & !grepl("district", a)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
a[.Last.value]
# [1] "this is a hospital"
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use two calls to `grepl`:

```
a[grepl("hospital", a) & !grepl("district", a)]
# [1] "this is a hospital"
```